# How to apply function over future index numbers - xts object

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have some stock data, in which I would like to apply a certain boolean value given that a certain previous boolean value is fulfilled in previous `n` rows.

The issue can simply be illustrated by a stock strategy of: Buy and hold for 30 days, how can this be achieved efficiently?

In the example data below, you can see several `TRUE (1)` value in the `Signal` column, now I would for example like to make the next 30 rows after an identified `1` value to `1` also. Note that the signal column may return `TRUE (1)` shortly after a `1` is observed, these value should be ignored and overridden.

Thus I need a behaviour similar to

1. Find first 1 in column Signal
2. Put 1 in the following n rows following the identified first 1, irrespective of if the row value for Signal column is 1 or 0.
3. Reset the behaviour, so that it starts to look for a 1 in Signal column again.

Example data

```
             Open   High    Low  Close Signal
2012-04-13 138.80 139.60 135.90 136.40      0
2012-04-16 136.00 141.30 135.20 139.70      1
2012-04-17 139.40 144.90 138.50 144.00      0
2012-04-18 139.90 140.10 135.60 136.30      0
2012-04-19 137.20 140.00 136.40 138.00      1
2012-04-20 137.60 141.00 136.10 141.00      0
2012-04-23 140.00 140.10 132.70 133.90      0
2012-04-24 133.90 138.40 133.40 138.20      0
2012-04-25 146.00 150.00 145.10 147.20      1
2012-04-26 149.80 149.80 144.20 146.00      0
2012-04-27 145.50 149.80 144.00 149.00      0
2012-04-30 148.50 150.60 147.60 150.10      0
2012-05-01 150.10 150.10 150.10 150.10      0
2012-05-02 151.10 151.10 147.80 148.80      0
2012-05-03 148.60 151.20 147.90 149.20      0
2012-05-04 148.40 149.20 140.50 143.00      0
2012-05-07 139.90 143.10 139.00 142.60      0
2012-05-08 142.30 142.30 137.80 138.60      0
2012-05-09 139.20 140.40 134.60 137.60      0
2012-05-10 139.00 141.30 136.10 140.00      0
2012-05-11 138.70 142.50 138.20 142.50      1
2012-05-14 140.60 141.70 135.30 136.20      0
2012-05-15 136.80 138.70 135.70 137.70      0
2012-05-16 135.60 136.50 132.00 135.60      0
2012-05-17 135.60 135.60 135.60 135.60      0
2012-05-18 132.10 134.30 129.50 130.90      0
2012-05-21 131.50 134.90 130.30 134.40      0
2012-05-22 135.20 139.70 133.50 138.60      0
2012-05-23 136.10 137.30 135.00 135.90      0
2012-05-24 137.40 140.10 135.60 137.60      0
2012-05-25 137.30 139.00 134.00 136.70      0
2012-05-28 137.80 141.30 137.30 139.20      0
2012-05-29 140.00 142.70 139.50 141.50      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one (which assumes that your xts object is called `x`):

```
n <- nrow(x)
i <- 1
x$Result <- x$Signal
while(i < n) {
  if(x$Signal[i]==1) {
    x$Result[(i+1):(min((i+30),n))] <- 1
    i <- min((i+31),n)
  } else i <- i+1
}
```